# What Laravel Eloquent Relationship Do I Use Here

Tags: php, laravel, database-design, eloquent

I have a board model and a pin model and each board contains all pins and each pin goes on every board. I am having a bit of trouble figuring out what Eloquent relationship to use and how to set this up.

I can share any code if needed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Let me know if my question isn't clear! Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is more inclined to database design than to Laravel, I think.

Comment: Ok should I use different tags?

Comment: you can remove eloquent tags and add a database design tag if there is one.

Comment: Ok thank you I will do that

Comment: I think Many to Many is the suitable choice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> each board contains all pins and each pin goes on every board

So **one** board may be associated to **many** pins, and **one** pin may be associated to **many** board: this is the definition of a [many to many relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

So `Board.php` may look like this:

```
class Board extends Model
{
    public function pins()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Pin');
    }
}
```

And `Pin.php`:

```
class Pin extends Model
{
    public function boards()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Board');
    }
}
```

Note that you need 3 tables in your database here: `boards`, `pins` and a pivot table `board_pin` which contains `board_id` and `pin_id` columns.

Comment: Thank you That makes a lot of sense!